# Очередь проверки, оценка внимательности

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, очередь-проверок, аудит

Зашел в очередь проверки, там одно сообщение. Ок, открыл.

Вспомнил, что такой вопрос уже задавали, проверил - действительно задавали, автор другой совсем. Написал комментарий, что это дубль и ссылку на предыдущий вопрос.

В ответ вот это

> СТОП! Читайте и запоминайте.
>
> Данная проверка была нужна для того, чтобы оценить вашу внимательность. Вы не прошли проверку. Ваша проверка оказалась неправильной. Это было хорошее сообщение, поэтому вам стоило оставить его без изменений или даже проголосовать в его пользу.
>
> Не волнуйтесь, мы уже позаботились об этом сообщении. Пожалуйста, уделите минуту и внимательно изучите его, учитывая вышеприведённые инструкции.

Цель то может и благая, но ощущения, как будто дерьмом облили.

Comment: Да, [такое бывает и с ответами](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2788/181100).

Comment: Eсли вы внимательно прочитали вопрос (или ответ), и правильно отнесли его в ту или другую категорию - то вам не за что волноваться.

Answer (score 6):

Ага, у меня тоже такое было. Думал, что это плагиат, оказалась проверка. Не беспокойтесь, это не повредит вашей учётной записи и очереди проверок не закроет. (Конечно, если не повторять это ещё N раз за непродолжительное время).

На будущее:

- Вопросы и ответы с настоящим плагиатом вроде бы не попадают в очередь проверок.
- Подделку видно по адресу, в нём id настоящего вопроса или ответа.

Спасибо за бдительность!

Comment: А каков механизм проверок? Регулярно натыкаюсь, один раз тоже попался. Ощущения так себе.