# На что влияют результаты оценки внимательности авторов проверок очередей?

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, аудит

Попал на 4 автооценки внимания при проверки очередей проверок. Прошёл 50/50. 
Ситуации. где я не "прошёл проверку" были спорными, но в целом понятными. 
Так вот вопрос, на что может повлиять низкий процент прохождения проверок?
Есть где-то подробное описание механизма формирования оценок внимания?

п.с.: нашёл похожий [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3363/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), но хотелось бы больше информации.

Comment: _Не беспокойтесь, это не повредит вашей учётной записи и очереди проверок не закроет. (**Конечно, если не повторять это ещё N раз за непродолжительное время**)._

Comment: @Grundy, прекрасно, но на что тогда влияет? Быть не может чтобы сделали эту довольно унизительную, порой, вещь просто так.

Comment: @Other, я там специально выделил часть про N раз за непродолжительное время.

Comment: @Grundy, и только?

Comment: @Grundy N мало, надо M.

Comment: Постарался ответить на ваш вопрос в публикации: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3563/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/3564#3564